# Filtrar consulta removendo duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Boa tarde, eu estou com o seguinte `select`:

```
select  codemp, codfunc, codevento
, vlrevento 
from sankhya.TFPFOL
where codemp = 1 
and codfunc = 26
and month(referencia) = 1
and year(referencia) = 2009
group by codemp, codfunc, codevento
, vlrevento
having count(1)=1
```

que me mostra o resultado abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que existem 2 campos com o `codevento` 534. Eu quero remover ambos mas manter o `vlrevento` para os demais.

Se eu removo o `vlrevento` do `GROUP BY` ele nao me permite completar o `SELECT`:

```
select  codemp, codfunc, codevento, vlrevento
from sankhya.TFPFOL
where codemp = 1 
and codfunc = 26
and month(referencia) = 1
and year(referencia) = 2009
group by codemp, codfunc, codevento

having count(1)=1
```

> ```
> Mensagem 8120, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 22
> A coluna 'sankhya.TFPFOL.VLREVENTO' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.
> ```

e se eu removo o `vlrevento` do select obviamente ele nao me mostra no resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso informar o campo `vlrevento` nesse `select` sem que apareça os `codeventos` que possuem valor duplicado?

Grato desde já

Comment: Você tem que informar o que vai fazer com `vlrevento`. Você quer mostrar o maior? O menor? Uma soma?

Comment: No caso seria apenas para informar o vlrevento correspondente ao codevento. Como eu quero remover os codevento que possuem valor duplicado eu nao preciso mostrar um min ou max. Os que estào repetidos eu não vou usar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrupe os registros e caso possua mais de um registro iremos remove-lo do nosso retorno utilizando a cláusula `HAVING`:

```
SELECT codemp, codfunc, codevento, SUM(vlrevento)
  FROM sankhya.TFPFOL
 WHERE codemp = 1 
   AND codfunc = 26
   AND month(referencia) = 1
   AND year(referencia) = 2009
 GROUP BY codemp, codfunc, codevento
HAVING count(codemp) = 1
```

Comment: é que eu não preciso daqueles codeventos duplicados. Então se eu só somar os vlrevento eles ainda vão aparecer na consulta

Comment: Se o `codevento` possuir mais de 1 registro você quer remover todos desse `codevento` do retorno?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Se existir algum codevento duplicado eu não vou precisar de nenhum deles

Comment: Tente novamente com essa edição.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Falou, abraços!!